# What can make a writeStream to emit close without writing to file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I want to merge chucks of file to another file but `writeStream` is emitting close without writing or appending the `readStream` content to the output file.

I have an `async` function with a for-of loop that iterates through the array and within the loop I created a `writableStream` with flag write truncate/write `w` flag if iteration index is 0 else append `w` then create a `readStream` then pipe it into `writeStream`.

```
 async function mergeBlocks(op) {
  for (const [index, block] of op.blockObjects.entries()) {
    const flags = index === 0? 'w' : 'a'
    const w = createWriteStream(op.output, { start: block.start, flags }),
      r = createReadStream(block.path, { start: block.start, end: block.end })
    console.log(index)
    r.pipe(w)
    await new Promise(res =>
      w.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('close')
        res()
      })
    )
  }
}
```

But it only write the first block and close the `writeStream` without writing to output file for on every other iteration. Please what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** Check answer below.

Comment: Why not create a single writeStream, and keep appending to it in the loop? If your current code produces error messages, please add them to your question.

Comment: @ChrisG that's the problem there's no error message but let try the one writeStream again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start` and `end` I was setting to the `createReadStream` options was not necessary I only have to set those if I am reading from on file by setting those only the first block will match the chunk start and end position which explains why is only to first chunk that's being written to file while other are just empty contents.
And as for code I ended up using promisify `stream.pipeline` which simplifies my code more.

```
async function mergeBlocks() {
  for (const [index, block] of op.blockObjects.entries()) {
    await pipeline(
      createReadStream(join(block.bucket, block.hash)),
      createWriteStream(op.output, { flags: index === 0 ? 'w' : 'a', start: block.start })
    )
  }
}
```